# JUnit a method with while loop and Async feature

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am having troubles testing the following method:

```
public class SomeClass {

  
    public void methodForTesting() {

        new Thread(() -> {
            SomeClass.stopSomething();
            while(SomeClass.getSomethingState() != SomethingState.DONE) {
                TimeUnit.sleep(5);
            }
            SomeClass.startSomething();
        });
    }
```

The methods with **SomeClass** in front are written without this addition but I have written it here to show that they are part of this class.
I am not sure how to approach this method and this while loop is botehring me.

Answer (score 0):

To (cover) test this method, you'd have to dig a little into (Power-)[mocking](/questions/tagged/mocking).

The **normal case** (`SomeClass.getSomethingState() == SomethingState.DONE` or otherwise) should be easy to test:

You'd want to verify, that  `SomeClass.stopSomething()`, `SomeClass.getSomethingState()`  and `SomeClass.startSomething()` has been called (in this "order").

For the **abnormal cases** (to reach [code-coverage](/questions/tagged/code-coverage)) you can instruct/mock to do any(-/no)thing and to return what you need (for any (also external) class/object):

E.g. on `SomeClass.getSomethingState()` but also on `Thread.sleep(anyIntger())`.

...

You can mock & verify also more complex things. E.g. (Instuct) that `SomeClass.getSomethingState()` results `x` times in (not) `DONE` and then changes on the `x+1`st time, and then verify (`stop-/start-/doSomething()`) acoordingly (with cardinality and parameters!).